# How to create a conditional validator with mongoose validators

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I currently have two validators running with my Mongoose Schema, however, I want to always execute the **first** one and the **second** validator I want executed based on a conditional, if a hyphen is present or not in the number string. How would I go about doing this?

Here is my code in question:

```
const manyValidators = [
    { validator: function(number) {
        const numberLength = number.length
        return ((numberLength >= 9 && number.includes('-') === true) || (numberLength >= 8 && number.includes('-') === false ))
    },
    message: "You must have at least 8 characters if you do not have a hyphen but 9 characters if you do."
    }, 
    { validator: function(number) {
        return (number.indexOf('-') === -1 && ((number.indexOf('-') === 2 || number.indexOf('-') === 3)))
    },
    message: "There should be at least 2 or 3 characters before the hyphen"
    }
]

const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: String,
    name: {
        type: String,
        minlength: [3, "Names must be of 3 characters minimum."],
        required: true
    },
    number: {
        type: String,
        validate: manyValidators,
        required: true
    }
})
```

The first validator consists of the "*You must have at least 8 characters if you do not have a hyphen but 9 characters if you do.*" **string** and the second one is the hyphen validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so blind, I realized that the validators themselves are functions so I added an `if` statement before the `return` statement in question to confirm if a hyphen is present or not via `indexOf`